# Reading multi-dimensional arrays - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having some issues on how to read arrays.
 console.log(arr[i][j]);  -- Can someone explain how the i and j fit into this. I'm printing the array i and j to the console, correct?

```
          function multiplyAll(arr) {
              var product = 1;

              // Only change code below this line
              var i = 0;
              var j = 0;

              for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {  
                for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {

                  console.log(arr[i][j]);                  
                  product *= arr[i][j];  

                }

              }



              // Only change code above this line
              return product;
            }

            // Modify values below to test your code
            multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
```

Comment: It's seems to be doing what you think it's doing. But why can't you check it yourself?

Comment: The code is correct but I looked up the answer, but unsure of what it does exactly. Im trying to put two and two together so I dont have to look anything up and just be able to figure it out in my head like I usually do

Comment: Since it's an array of arrays you're passing in, it encapsulates 2 loops. The outer one is looping over the main array (and its indexer is `i`) while the inner loop is looping over each nested array (and its indexer is `j`). The expression `arr[i][j]` yields the actual value in each of the inner arrays (1,2,3,4,5,6,7).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the j-th element of the i-th array to the console.